# How to create a bottom aligned label in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, interface-builder

There are several examples on how to create a Top Aligned label in Swift. Here is on that works for me:

```
@IBDesignable class TopAlignedLabel: UILabel {
    override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {
        if let stringText = text {
            let stringTextAsNSString = stringText as NSString
            var labelStringSize = stringTextAsNSString.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), CGFloat.max),
                options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin,
                attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font],
                context: nil).size
            super.drawTextInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), ceil(labelStringSize.height)))
        } else {
            super.drawTextInRect(rect)
        }
    }
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    }
}
```

I am trying to modify this to create a bottom aligned label, but struggling to find the right thing to change. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```
super.drawTextInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), ceil(labelStringSize.height)))
```

Into this:

```
super.drawTextInRect(CGRectMake(0, rect.size.height - labelStringSize.height, CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), ceil(labelStringSize.height)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating the solution for **SWIFT 3.0**, complete code becomes:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class BottomAlignedLabel: UILabel {
override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
    if let stringText = text {
        let stringTextAsNSString = stringText as NSString
        let labelStringSize = stringTextAsNSString.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: self.frame.width,height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude),
                                                                options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                                                attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font],
                                                                context: nil).size
        super.drawText(in: CGRect(x:0,y: rect.size.height - labelStringSize.height, width: self.frame.width, height: ceil(labelStringSize.height)))
    } else {
        super.drawText(in: rect)
    }
}
override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    layer.borderWidth = 1
    layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
}
```

}